# Cypher: One aggregate function on top of the other

Tags: neo4j, cypher, aggregate

I am looking for a way to perform one aggregate function on top of the results of another one. In particular, I would like to join the following two queries:

```
MATCH (e :Event) - [:ATTENDED_BY] -> (a :Person)
WITH e, collect(a) AS attendants
WHERE ALL (a in attendants WHERE a.Company="XYZ")
RETURN e.name AS name, count(*) as number_occurrences
ORDER BY number_events DESC;

MATCH (e:Event) - [:ATTENDED_BY] -> (a :Person)
WITH e, collect(a) AS attendants
WHERE ALL (a in attendants WHERE a.Company="XYZ")
WITH e.name AS name, count(*) as number_occurrences
RETURN percentileDisc(number_occurrences,0.95) as percentile;
```

The first query gives all the event names wwhere only people from a single company ("XYZ") attended, as well as the number of occurrences of those events. The second one returns the minimum number of occurrences for the top 5% most frequent events. What I would like to get is the names and number of occurrences of these 5% most frequent events. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the query using WITH clause, of course, but the key was to understand its usageproperly. The idea is that only the variables passed with the last WITH clause are visible further. That is why after we get the "percentile" variable in the first part of the query, we need to keep on passing it in the second part of the query in all the subsequent WITH clauses.

```
MATCH (e :Event) - [:ATTENDED_BY] -> (a :Person)
WITH e, collect(a) AS attendants
WHERE ALL (a in attendants WHERE a.Company="XYZ")
WITH e.name AS name, count(*) as number_occurences
WITH percentileDisc(number_occurencies,0.95) as percentile
MATCH (e :Event) - [:ATTENDED_BY] -> (a :Person)
WITH percentile, e, collect(a) AS attendants
WHERE ALL (a in attendants WHERE a.Company="XYZ")
WITH percentile, e.name AS name, count(*) as number_occurences
WHERE number_occurences > percentile
RETURN name, number_occurences
ORDER BY number_occurences DESC
```